# Bare-bones Amidah

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei

If you are pressed for time during prayer, would it be OK to say only the blessings when you come to the Amidah, and skip the rest?  I know it's not officially sanctioned, but would it be acceptable?

Comment: What blessings specifically?

Comment: You're probably better off saying Havinenu.

Comment: @RabbiKaii. All nineteen.

Comment: Oh, you mean just the ending of each bracha? It's pretty hard to decipher your question.

Comment: @shmosel  --  I mean: just everything that starts with Baruch atta Hashem.

Comment: From the Mishnah Berurah 124:41 it seems that at least with regards to “Modim” that the beginning is essential, and one is not Yotzei without it.

Comment: Also, from the fact that the “Baruch Attah” in Shemone Esrei is called a “Chatimah”, shows that by definition there must be something recited prior.

Answer (score 3):

The text on this page is the shortest Amidah available.

https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Havinenu

Comment: But we don't say it today.

Comment: Who is we? As per the Halachipedia page you can if you are sick

Comment: See the first subsection.

Comment: It says "should" it does not say its forbidden

Comment: I didn't say it's forbidden.

Comment: Ok well then who is we?